# youtube api V3 quota cost? - making an app that allows user to upload to their account

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

If you set up a OAuth for Youtube within your app that allows users to upload videos, does each video cost towards your 10,000pt quota?

I run a personal uploading bot and it does 3ish uploads per day within the 10,000 point quota but if I was to scale out as an app this wouldn't work since 5 users would max it out.

**So if a user approves your app for upload permissions, would this cost toward your clients 10,000pts or is it 10,000 points per user per day?**

Also how easy is YouTube's quota expansion form process if it is the former?
https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) you will be able to see what each call costs.  The vido.insert call for example costs 1600 quota.

If you check the google developer console and check your quota it might look something like this.

[image]

As you can see one of them states "per user" while the other does not.

Queries per day 10,000 is a project based quota. while Queries per minute per user is a user based quota.

It sounds like you should be applying for a quota extension if the 10,000 limit is not enough for your needs.

> Also how easy is YouTube's quota expansion form process if it is the former?

Its a long process google says it takes twenty days my experience is three to six months average.  You need to be prepared to get a NO.  You also need to be prepared to have your quota shut down suddenly because they detect something they identity as spam or a violation.  In the event of a shutdown you will need to apply for a new extension.  Which again will take time.